# Adding outlook resource calender to Sharepoint 2013 and Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, online

Trying to figure out how could I add the resource calender to SPOnline and SP2013. We want to have calendar overview in our sharepoint but I don't really have an idea how to do it. How could I connect Outlook calenders and display them in SP?

Currently working with SPOnline cloud and SP2013. If I am able to duplicate that on SP2013 I believe I will be able to do on SPOnline with classic page

Answer (score 0):

We could create a calendar overlay to create a view for exchange calendar in calendar list.

More references:

https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-overlay-sharepoint-calendars/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overlay-a-sharepoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-exchange-or-sharepoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us